# Explode JSON key Value to new Rows

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking to convert a nested JSON and explode it to new rows.

The current data:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------+
|         id|      site |                         sale|
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|        abc|          6|{"2019-05-08T00:00:00": null, "2019-05-09T00:00:00": [{"key1": 2, "key2": 0}]}         |
|        def|          5|{"2019-05-08T00:00:00": [{"key1": 22, "key2": 10}], "2019-05-09T00:00:00": null}       |
|        ghi|          4|{"2019-05-08T00:00:00": null, "2019-05-09T00:00:00": null}         |
```

Desired result

```
+-----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+-----------+
|         id|      site |                saledate|       key1|       key2|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        abc|          6|     2019-05-08T00:00:00|       null|       null|
|        abc|          6|     2019-05-09T00:00:00|          2|          0|
|        def|          5|     2019-05-08T00:00:00|         22|         10|
|        def|          5|     2019-05-09T00:00:00|       null|       null|
|        ghi|          4|     2019-05-08T00:00:00|       null|       null|
|        ghi|          4|     2019-05-09T00:00:00|       null|       null|
```

### What I have tried:

- `explode` works only for `Array` type.

```
new_df = old_df.withColumn('saledate', explode('sale'))
```

- I'm able to get properties of each date by doing the following. However, I would have to specify each date separately, which is not ideally.

```
new_df = old_df
  .withColumn('sale_collection', explode('sale.2019-05-08T00:00:00'))
  .withColumn('key1', col('sale_collection').getItem('key1')
  .withColumn('key2', col('sale_collection').getItem('key2')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [from_json](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) to convert the string into a Map and then explode:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json

df.withColumn('sale', from_json('sale', 'map<string,array<struct<key1:int,key2:int>>>')) \
  .selectExpr('*', 'explode_outer(sale) as (saledate, keys)') \
  .selectExpr('id', 'site', 'saledate', 'inline_outer(keys)') \
  .show()
+---+----+-------------------+----+----+
| id|site|           saledate|key1|key2|
+---+----+-------------------+----+----+
|abc|   6|2019-05-08T00:00:00|null|null|
|abc|   6|2019-05-09T00:00:00|   2|   0|
|def|   5|2019-05-08T00:00:00|  22|  10|
|def|   5|2019-05-09T00:00:00|null|null|
|ghi|   4|2019-05-08T00:00:00|null|null|
|ghi|   4|2019-05-09T00:00:00|null|null|
+---+----+-------------------+----+----+
```

**Note:** [inline_outer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#inline_outer) and [inline](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#inline) are SparkSQL builtin functions to explode an array of structs.

Comment: Thanks @jxc. The only thing is that `sale` column has Struct data type, not string. I _believe_ `from_json` only going to work with StringType.
And the reason it's Struct type (instead of String) is because the data is loaded using `spark.read`

Comment: just do: `from_json(to_json('sale'), 'map<string,array<struct<key1:int,key2:int>>>'))` and make sure to import `to_json`. @stack247

Comment: That did it.
Just curious... do you know the syntax if I were to use `explode_outer` (or `explode`) in `withColumn` ?

Comment: @stack247, you can not explode MapType column using withColumn since it yields two columns.